# Magento admin form time field

Tags: forms, magento, magento-1.7, timefield

I am trying to add a time field to an admin form but it does not work:

```
    $fieldset->addField('sched_time', 'time', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('servicemanager')->__('Scheduled Time'),
      'style'     => 'width:45px',
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'sched_time',
      'value'  => '09,00,00',
    ));
```

The problems are as follows:

1. The data isn't getting stored in the database ('sched_time' is a mysql time field)
2. 'value' doesn't do anything. I need the default value to be set to 09:00:00 (9am)

Reference: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

Comment: What format is your time field 'HH:MM:SS'?

Comment: Yes, the format is HH:MM:SS

Comment: why you have used `Mage::helper('servicemanager')`? Is `servicemanager` is your module name?

Comment: Yes, servicemanager was the module name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some code manually in your controller's `saveAction()` method which might look like:

```
public function saveAction(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($id);
    $time = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sched_time');
    $sched_time = $time[0] . ':' . $time[1] . ':' . $time[2]; //HH:MM:SS
    $model->setData('sched_time', $sched_time);
    $model->save();
}
```

Hope this will help future visitors!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an observer, after hours trying to find this myself I came across this link [magento weight attribute without decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401771/magento-weight-attribute-without-decimal-points)

Hope this helps as it helped me