# magento weight attribute without decimal points

Tags: magento

I need to show weight attribute without any decimal points in admin panel on front end that is working fine but I need to remove the 4 decimal points from admin panel where site admin enter the product details.

Any help in terms of code or database changes will be appreciated.

image url : http://sale24by7.com/weight.png

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Event

```
adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form
```

To catch the form output and modify it as you want !

The method will look like this :

```
   public function renderWeight( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {
        $form = $observer->getForm();
        $element = $form->getElement('weight'); // Weight attribute from the Form Data
        if($element){
            $oldWeight = $element->getValue(); // Weight Value you want to modify
            $values['weight'] = (int) $oldWeight; // Assign the new Weight Value
            $form->addValues($values); // Add it to the form
        }
    }
```

I have created the module you downloaded from here [Download](http://meabed.net/eproduct.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I just use this:

.$this->htmlEscape(number_format($weight));

Comment: where did you add this line?

Answer (score 0):

To change the decimal precision of attributes that have a backend_type set to decimal,

You have to change the type of value in this table :

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

If you have not change yet, you should see :

```
decimal(12,4)
```

You should replace with

```
decimal(12,0)
```